# I want when I click on a word in the webview, a dialog will open for that text

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

[Dialog not show when I click to text from WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUBeg.png)

I want when I click on a word in the webview, a dialog will open for that text, but nothing happens.

[image: When I click it only show FrameEvents( 4172): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.]

This is full code

```
child: InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://your-website.com")),
          onLoadResource: (controller, resource) async {
            // Inject JavaScript code to handle click event on text
            await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: '''
              document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                var target = event.target;
                if (target.nodeType === 3) {
                  // Your custom logic when text is clicked
                  console.log('Clicked on text:', target.textContent);
                  
                  // Send the clicked text to Flutter for further processing
                  if (window.flutter_inappwebview) {
                    window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('textClicked', target.textContent);
                  }
                }
              });
            ''');
          },
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            webView = controller;
            // Add JavaScript handler to receive clicked text from webview
            controller.addJavaScriptHandler(handlerName: 'textClicked', callback: (args) {
              String clickedText = args[0];
              // Display a dialog with the clicked text
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Clicked Text"),
                    content: Text("You clicked on the text: $clickedText"),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text("OK"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            });
          },
        ),
```